# Create a new column in a dataframe based on a date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I’m new in python and I would like to add a column based on a date with several condition.
My data came from a sheet.

Currently my code looks like this :

```
#Save data in a DataFrame

df1 = pd.read_excel(stream_io1, sheet_name = "Sheet1", header=0)

# Use Accounting Date 
df1['Item - Accounting Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Item - Accounting Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

def condition(row):
    if (row['Item - Accounting Date'] < '2020-01-01') in row['Item - Accounting Date']:
        return "<2020"
    if "2020" in row['Item - Accounting Date']:
        return "2020"
    if (row[(row['Item - Accounting Date'] >= "01/01/2021") & (row['Item - Accounting Date'] <="30/06/2021")]) in row['Item - Accounting Date']:
        return "S1 2021"    
    if (row[(row['Item - Accounting Date'] > "30/06/2021") & (row['Item - Accounting Date'] <="31/12/2021")]) in row['Item - Accounting Date']:
        return "S2 2021" 

df1['Année'] = df1.apply(condition, axis = 1)
```

And I have this error message :

**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'**

I understand the error but I don’t know how to resolve it

Comment: use a format like `"2021-06-30"` **consistently** instead of `"30/06/2021"` in the comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you only need to apply `condition` function to one column, so you can fix it as below using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
def condition(row):
    if row < pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'):
        return "<2020"
    if "2020" in row:
        return "2020"
    if (row >= pd.Timestamp("2021-01-01")) & (row <=pd.Timestamp("2021-06-30")):
        return "S1 2021"    
    if (row > pd.Timestamp("2021-06-30")) & (row <=pd.Timestamp("2021-12-31")):
        return "S2 2021" 

df1['Année'] = df1['Item - Accounting Date'].apply(condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
```

this is how you can convert string to datetime object

Comment: Hi @Shen, do I add it directly on the condition : `row['Item - Accounting Date'] < dt.strptime("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")` ? Because When I do that I have this following error **TypeError: argument of type 'Timestamp' is not iterable**

Comment: OP is using pandas. With pandas, you'll want to use pandas datetime, not the standard lib's datetime.